# How to create https client with synapse?

Tags: delphi, https, httpclient, ararat-synapse

I need a https client used with synapse.

Do you have any demo about it?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried example from Synapse How-To: [Using Tcp With Ssl On Tcp Client](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:tcpwithssl) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SynHttp := THTTPSend.Create;
SynHttp.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);
SynHttp.Sock.SSLDoConnect;
SynHttp.HTTPMethod('GET', 'https://www.google.com');
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(SynHttp.Document);
```